# iPhone - setValue:forkey: not documented

Tags: objective-c, iphone, reference, key-value-coding

I have these lines in my code :

```
[defaults setValue:someValue forKey:@"someValue"];
[animationGroup setValue:@"someValue" forKey:@"someValue"];  // CAAnimationGroup
NSString* animName = [theAnimation valueForKey:@"someValue"]; // CAAnimation
```

But reading the Apple Reference Documentation :

- https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimationGroup_class/Introduction/Introduction.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation

I don't see any reference to these methods, even parsing hierarchy or conformed protocols. From where do they come ? Is their use allowed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are Key-Value Coding methods; if those classes are Key-Value Coding compliant for those keys, then you can use them without issue. With respect to Core Animation, both `CALayer` and `CAAnimation` are KVC compliant, as detailed in [this programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/KVCAdditions.html). For more general information, refer to the [`NSKeyValueCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/NSKeyValueCoding) informal protocol and the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

Comment: Do you know why the NSKeyValueCoding Protocol is not referencend in the "Conforms to" section of these classes ?

Comment: `NSKeyValueCoding` is an informal protocol, which are defined as categories on `NSObject` (see the `NSKeyValueCoding.h` header file) and not explicit protocols as implementation is optional.

Answer (score 3):

As a side note that confused me as well.  One of the links above provides:

> Both CALayer and CAAnimation are key-value coding compliant container
>   classes, allowing you to set values for arbitrary keys. That is, while
>   the key “someKey” is not a declared property of the CALayer class,
>   however you can still set a value for the key “someKey”

meaning that you can safely send KVC-like setValue:forKey: and valueForKey: messages and not have to worry about the fact that @"someKey" is not a real KVC-compliant property (hence "arbitrary keys").  If you try this on other objects, exceptions may be thrown.  I admit I'm not sure how to find out *easily* if other classes have this behavior, it certainly would be useful to have this behavior for free in many other places.